# Axios : How to run multiple requests one after the other?

Tags: javascript, api, asynchronous, axios

I have a very large array of IDs (thousands of IDs). I want to loop through this array and for each value, make a request to an API like so :

```js
[12, 32, 657, 1, 67, ...].forEach((id) => {
    axios.get(`myapi.com/user/${id}`).then(({ data }) => {
        console.log(data.name);
    });
});
```

However, I have so many requests to make I can't make them asynchronous because my computer has limits... Is it possible to wait for each request to be finished before making the next one ?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using `forEach` in id try [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

```
const ids = [12, 32, 657, 1, 67];
const promises = ids.map((id) => axios.get(`myapi.com/user/${id}`));

Promise.all([...promises]).then(function (values) {
  console.log(values);
});
```

> Let’s say we want many promises to execute in parallel and wait until
> all of them are ready.
>
> For instance, download several URLs in parallel and process the
> content once they are all done.

From https://javascript.info/promise-api

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume that you allow `n` requests to be sent maximum at any given time. For the sake of the example I assume it's 10:

```
var n = 10;
```

We also store the current index:

```
var index = 0;
```

Let's implement a function to handle the requests:

```
function req() {
    axios.get(`myapi.com/user/${input[index]}`).then(({ data }) => {
        console.log(data.name);
        if (index + 1 < input.length) {
            index++;
            req();
        }
    });    
}
```

Then, let's send the first `n` requests:

```
while (index < n) {req(); index++}
```

Yes, `index` is global, but it is global for the sake of readability.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But am I right in thinking there's a maximum number of recursions I can make ? I have ~ 500 000 calls to make.

Comment: @tomfl you have a very specific situation which was probably not planned by those who implemented your browser. I encourage you to experiment with a dummy function, instead of actually sending requests, do a setTimeout with 50 milliseconds and leave other parts of the idea unchanged. That should answer your concern. Please let me know about the result, I'm interested about it as well.

Comment: If recursion does not break the system with calls to setTimeout instead of request sending, then it is quasi proof that you will have no problem with recursion either. If recursion breaks the system, then alternatively you can poll for status via setInterval and manage a slot system for your requests. Or, you can always have packets of n elements and await for the requests.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, it's clear you have to redesign your api.

However, you can try:

```js
Promise.all([12, 32, 657, 1, 67, ...].map((id) => {
    return axios.get(`myapi.com/user/${id}`).then(({ data }) => {
        console.log(data.name);
    });
})).then(_=>console.log('done'));
```

or look into [p-queue](https://github.com/sindresorhus/p-queue) which will help you manage the queue of promises.