# for loop with axios, how do I know if all data are loaded

Tags: javascript, axios

```
this.allMyFacilities = response[1].data
          for (let i = 0; i < this.allMyFacilities.length; i++) {
            axios
              .get(facilityUsed(this.allMyFacilities[i].id))
              .then((response) => {
                this.facilitiesOnSupplyChain[this.allMyFacilities[i].id] = response.data
              })
              .catch((err) => {
                // An error will also be thrown if you use cancel.
                console.error(err)
              })
          }
```

I have such a code. I don't know how many facilities do I have. that is I loop it, But each facility has its own Axios. I want to how do I know all data from the loop are completely  loaded

Comment: You can use `async` function with `await` instead of `then()` or you can use `Promise.all()`.

Comment: Please take a look at this answer I think it's a case similar to the one you have https://stackoverflow.com/a/62628934/615274

Comment: @Elias, do you want to accept any of the given answers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) for this:

```
this.allMyFacilities = response[1].data
const promises = this.allMyFacilities.map((myFacility) => {
    return axios
        .get(facilityUsed(myFacility.id))
        .then((response) => {
            this.facilitiesOnSupplyChain[myFacility.id] = response.data
            return response.data;
        }).catch((err) => {
            // An error will also be thrown if you use cancel.
            console.error(err)
        });
});
Promise.all(promises).then((allResponsesArray) => /* do sth */)
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that all the asynchronous calls can be made independently, you can leverage upon the `Promise.all` functionality to achieve this.

```
this.allMyFacilities = response[1].data
await Promise.all(this.allMyFacilities.map(myFacility) => {
  return axios.get(facilityUsed(myFacility.id))
    .then(data => this.facilitiesOnSupplyChain[myFacility.id] =  data);
});
```

This will allow you to execute all the `axios` calls in parallel, and hence decrease the overall execution time of the whole process.

PS:
I have written an `await` statement hance assuming that you will be wrapping this functionality in an `async` function.